# CSS3 Snow Fall Animation Disable internal links

Tags: html, css, animation, snowfall

I want to using Snow Fall Animation by using CSS3. But when i use css code, my sites most of internal links disabled. Also i can not select any content from site.

here my code :

```
body { background-color:#333; }
#snow{
    background: none;
    font-family: Androgyne;
    background-image: url('http://www.wearewebstars.dk/codepen/img/s1.png'), url('http://www.wearewebstars.dk/codepen/img//s2.png'), url('http://www.wearewebstars.dk/codepen/img//s3.png');
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index:1;
    -webkit-animation: snow 10s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: snow 10s linear infinite;
    -ms-animation: snow 10s linear infinite;
    animation: snow 10s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes snow {
  0% {background-position: 0px 0px, 0px 0px, 0px 0px;}
  50% {background-position: 500px 500px, 100px 200px, -100px 150px;}
  100% {background-position: 500px 1000px, 200px 400px, -100px 300px;}
}
@-moz-keyframes snow {
  0% {background-position: 0px 0px, 0px 0px, 0px 0px;}
  50% {background-position: 500px 500px, 100px 200px, -100px 150px;}
  100% {background-position: 400px 1000px, 200px 400px, 100px 300px;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes snow {
  0% {background-position: 0px 0px, 0px 0px, 0px 0px;}
  50% {background-position: 500px 500px, 100px 200px, -100px 150px;}
  100% {background-position: 500px 1000px, 200px 400px, -100px 300px;}
}
@-ms-keyframes snow {
  0% {background-position: 0px 0px, 0px 0px, 0px 0px;}
  50% {background-position: 500px 500px, 100px 200px, -100px 150px;}
  100% {background-position: 500px 1000px, 200px 400px, -100px 300px;}
}
```

Comment: Like thejoin mentions in their answer, the z-index of #snow needs to be less than the z-index of any content you want to be able to have interactions with the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have set the CSS of an element to pointer-events: none, it won’t catch any click on it at all, but instead just let the event fall through to the element below it. Need use 'pointer-events: none;' 
whole code like this:

```
    #snow{
    background-image: url('/assets/images/s1.png'),
            url('/assets/images/s2.png'),
            url('/assets/images/s3.png');
    height: 100%;
        pointer-events: none;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index:1;
    -webkit-animation: snow 10s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: snow 10s linear infinite;
    -ms-animation: snow 10s linear infinite;
    animation: snow 10s linear infinite;
}
/*Keyframes*/
@keyframes snow { 0% { background-position: 500px 0px, 120px 0px, -100px 0px; }
       10% { background-position: 500px 100px, 120px 40px, -100px 30px; }
       20% { background-position: 500px 200px, 120px 80px, -100px 60px; }
       30% { background-position: 500px 300px, 120px 120px, -100px 90px; }
       40% { background-position: 500px 400px, 120px 160px, -100px 120px; }
       50% { background-position: 500px 500px, 120px 200px, -100px 150px; }
       60% { background-position: 500px 600px, 120px 240px, -100px 180px; }
       70% { background-position: 500px 700px, 120px 280px, -100px 210px; }
       80% { background-position: 500px 800px, 120px 320px, -100px 240px; }
       90% { background-position: 500px 900px, 120px 360px, -100px 270px; }
       100% { background-position: 500px 1000px, 120px 400px, -100px 300px; } }

@-moz-keyframes snow {
0% {background-position: 0px 0px, 0px 0px, 0px 0px;}
100% {background-position: 500px 1000px, 400px 400px, 300px 300px;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes snow {
0% {background-position: 0px 0px, 0px 0px, 0px 0px;}
 100% {background-position: 500px 1000px, 400px 400px, 300px 300px;}
}

@-ms-keyframes snow {
0% {background-position: 0px 0px, 0px 0px, 0px 0px;}
 100% {background-position: 500px 1000px, 400px 400px, 300px 300px;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a z-index problem. 
Can you post your html just to complete your answer?

If you don't have any container or any different background in pages, you can put the snowfall effect at your `body`, like a `background-image`.

I mean:

```
body{
     background-color: #333;
     background-image: url('http://www.wearewebstars.dk/codepen/img/s1.png'), url('http://www.wearewebstars.dk/codepen/img//s2.png'), url('http://www.wearewebstars.dk/codepen/img//s3.png');
    -webkit-animation: snow 10s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: snow 10s linear infinite;
    -ms-animation: snow 10s linear infinite;
    animation: snow 10s linear infinite;
}
```

Comment: I use '<div id="snow"></div>' after body. I have many container in my page.  I have some background image in other sections.